# Can I use another .xml file in values/strings.xml file?

Tags: android

I have a question about values/strings.xml
I'd like to use strings.xml, but use another strings.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
    <string name="test">veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery long script(about 1000characters)</string>
</resources>
```

like this, when I want to manage veeeeery long script by another xml file.
Then can I use another .xml file in values/strings.xml file?

for example like..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
    <string name="test"> @values/script.xml </string>
</resources>
```

Thank you for reading my question.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: You can put your long text file inside a raw directory (res -> raw -> script.xml). You can then retrieve it like this: `InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.script.xml);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to use @string instead of @values